# Should GitHub's "Fork" button not be a button?

Tags: website-design, forms

As a repository creator, I often find entries on my "news feed" indicating people have forked my Git.  However, in being actively involved with all contributors, I also see that most time people fork my git, only about 20% of the forks come from a user who *intends* to contribute (and perhaps the others meant to star, instead).

When I look at a much more popular repo for Discourse, I see this is a huge pattern, but even more :

[image]

Looking at the list of all people who have forked this repo, I have checked a few dozen and see no contributions have also ever been made: https://github.com/discourse/discourse/network/members

There are 336 actual contributors, but 2800+ forks. Here, just like in my scenario, are a large amount of what I'd consider "accidental" forks.  This action is not "undo-able" (you can delete your git, but it's immensely more involving, unlike gmail delete undo).

Considering the number of "accidental" forks, should this input element be something different, such as the neighboring Watch button (which requires two clicks)?  Or is this model intended for vanity--exploiting consistent user error to inflate the apparent interest in any given project?

Comment: A somewhat unfinished thought, but it seems that the workflow for sharing branches, pull requests, etc, is simpler if you start with your own fork, rather than cloning the upstream repo directly and only later realising you want to make a change. So "speculatively" forking a project is not necessarily something to be discouraged, since you want a low barrier to entry if someone does come up with something worth sharing.

Comment: I agree with IMSo. I'd question whether forks without contributions are necessarily accidental. I regularly fork stuff I'm interested with to play with locally, but end up not doing anything with it. I've never forked anything accidentally that I can recall.

Comment: Perhaps then I've misspoken in terminology. I don't mean to imply that all these non-contributor forks are mistakes in clicking, but rather that it is not the intent to ever be a contributor and it is the case that people could be functionally served by cloning the root project, but instead fork and clone a derived one. In some of the most popular repos, there are ratios more akin to 23000 forks to 500 contributors, where the question then is: are there really tens of thousands of people who "intend" to modify, but never do--even their own fork? Or is forking just a convenience (typingwise)

Comment: TLDR; *i may have included speculation, but I am seeking an answer that is not opinion based. It is hopefully possible through research that is not my own to determine whether the workflow presented by GitHub is encouraging forking even for users who don't intend to contribute at any point. Since we know that it is literally not required to fork in order to use something locally, my question focuses on whether GitHub is failing to demonstrate a viable, alternate means of accomplishing a task.

Comment: Similar question on programmers stackexchange. [people fork my project but don't fetch from upstream - what can I do?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/139234/people-fork-my-project-but-dont-fetch-from-upstream-what-can-i-do)

Answer (score 0):

The fork feature is one of the important ones on GitHub. I don't think it should be tuned-down.

You are right that Github could have offered an easier way to undo forking, but I doubt it will massively change the amount of forks. To begin with, GitHub main persona is a developer with knowledge of git and GitHub - I doubt people just fork things by mistake or to see what happens.

Also, once forked, you see the repository on your account, so surely forking for fun isn't such a common practice.

There is high contributors/forks ratios for many other projects on Github, yet some have a lower one.

I can only speculate that a high fork to contributions ratio is typical in a highly attractive project, the codebase of which may be not easy to contribute to. So people fork, try to solve an issue, then give up. But it isn't alway the case.

In other words, I think the theory that these forks are largely "accidental" isn't a correct one.

Comment: The fact that the repo shows up in your account, but the high incidence of those unable-or-unwilling to fork kind of gets to the crux of the question: would making a "are you sure" mechanism (such as a two click process or dialog) in any practical sense inhibit intended forks--and will doing so reduce what I insist are "accidental"?  Where's the downside?

Comment: An "are you sure" mechanism would definitely serve as an excellent guard here from slips or mistakes (ie, user errors); it comes at low-cost, since users don't perform such action frequently enough for the guard (and additional click) to annoy them. But I'd argue that with even such guard in place, the amount of forks will be only slightly reduced. Would be great if you can approach some of those who forked the repository and ask them why they did so.

Comment: The downside is an extra level of annoyance every time I fork. That little "yes I *am* sure - that's why I clicked on the button" that rolls around my head. And which quickly becomes an automatic click, removing the value in stopping accidental clicks... which so far we have no evidence for actually existing ;-)

Comment: I fork by accident all the time. Just try to write a URL that contains the letter 'e' when viewing a file without focusing the address bar. Boom, automatic fork.